# How to read and parse only 1 column from a CSV file Java

Tags: java, csv

So I have a CSV file in which I have several attributes of books, in face of bookName, authorName, yearOfPublishing, etc. In order to process the file I am implementing batch framework. The problem is that I want to read and parse only the authorName field, and my app doesn't recognise it, it only passes the first column of my CSV file into my authorName field. Here is my item reader and line mapper.

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader<Author> reader(){
    FlatFileItemReader<Author> itemReader = new FlatFileItemReader<>();
    itemReader.setResource(new FileSystemResource("src/main/resources/BX-Books.csv"));
    itemReader.setName("csvReader");
    itemReader.setLinesToSkip(1);
    itemReader.setLineMapper(lineMapper());
    itemReader.setStrict(false);
    return itemReader;
}

private LineMapper<Author> lineMapper() {
    DefaultLineMapper<Author> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<>();

    DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
    lineTokenizer.setDelimiter(";");
    lineTokenizer.setStrict(false);
    lineTokenizer.setNames("Book-Author");

    BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Author> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
    fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(Author.class);

    lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
    lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);
    return lineMapper;
}
```

Comment: Isn't https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/transform/DelimitedLineTokenizer.html#setIncludedFields-int...- what you need?

Comment: I will post it as an answer. Please accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[THIS](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/transform/DelimitedLineTokenizer.html#setIncludedFields-int...-) would be the way to do it.

That would be the method `setIncludedFields` in class `org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer` in case the above link goes bad.

Comment: I think it's better to provide context for your link, as in https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer -- the link could be deprecated and your answer would not have much value.

Comment: OK, good point. Fixed